# Return data to the view in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I do have a table "words" and it has 2 columns "word" and "countofletters"

When I get them in the controller, how can I return them to the view based on the count, basically the view should contain something like:

4 letter words:

1- climb

2- Play

---

3 letter words:

1- put

2- cut

---

And so on..

Comment: Use a loop and that should do it

Comment: Base on how `words` table is big, we have some scenarios to reach your expected results. Simplest way is retrieve all and group by `countofletters`. For example `DB::table('words')->get()->groupBy('countofletters');`

If the table is too large, I suggest we extract only distinct values of `countofletters`, preload X words of each value.

Answer (score 0):

## Return from controller

You can send data to the view with `compact` instruction :

```php
$yourDataFetchedFromDB = "";
return view('myviews.view', compact('yourDataFetchedFromDB'));
```

## In your view

You can now access the value of `$yourDataFetchedFromDB` in your view as if you were in your controller.
Now you can use something like :

```php
<ul>
@foreach($yourDataFetchedFromDB as $row)
    <li>$row->word</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

And to use count columns you can use :

```php
$yourDataFetchedFromDB[0]->countofletters
```

#### Full view code

```php
<h2>{{ $yourDataFetchedFromDB[0]->countofletters }}</h2>
<ul>
@foreach($yourDataFetchedFromDB as $row)
    <li>$row->word</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Note : Obviously you should check if `$yourDataFetchedFromDB[0]` is not empty before using it

Comment: But this would list all the words under each other, my idea is to seperate them by count of letter, so basically you will have a <div> for  4-letters words and list the 4 letter words and then under that you will have a <div> for 3 letter words and list the 3 letter words and so on..

Comment: Yeah this would be a little more tricky, I don't know if there is a specific syntax in eloquent for this but if not, the best way should be by looping an ordering "manually"